# JavaScript Bookmarklet Error to Click on Specific Buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet that will allow me to clip all coupons on the webpage https://www.heb.com/digital-coupon/coupon-selection/all-coupons.

The code doesn't work, I get 'Illegal Invocation' errors but I don't know how to solve them.

```js
javascript:(function(){
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`button.sc-1r7h1ka-0.sc-l8uhjs-0.ikNqYG.JCvzH.sc-1xu2rpv-8.enkMAU`);
  for (const button of buttons) {
    setTimeout(button.click, 100);
  }
})();
```

Comment: `button.click.bind(button)`